# Switching Frame

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, keylistener

I'm trying to switch from one frame to another by a button. Here is my first frame code:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(width,height);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Icon play = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("play.png"));
    startB = new JButton(play);
    startB.setBounds(105,350,100,35);
    startB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            f.dispose();
            MainProgram mp = new MainProgram();
            mp.run();

        }
    });
```

and the MainProgram:

```
//run method
            public void run() {
                init();
                gameLoop();
            }

//init method
public void init() {
    s = new screen();
    rand = new Random();
    upPipes = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    downPipes = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

    DisplayMode dm = s.compareDisplayModes(modes);
    s.setFullScreen(dm);

    Window w = s.getFullScreenWindow();
    w.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 50));
    w.setForeground(Color.PINK);
    w.addKeyListener(this);
    w.setFocusable(true);

    loadPics();
    running = true;
}
```

But when the MainProgram's frame is on the screen, it doesn't listen to my keyboard even though I have already added key listener. Is that because the first frame is only disposed but not closed? Is there anyway to close it or to make my frame listen to my keyboard?

Comment: You might want to request focus?

Comment: One more thing, what is your game loop doing? If your game loop is running on the edt, it will not let your app update.

Comment: thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, replace this:

```
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

with

```
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

You try to get rid of the frame later, that would make your application exit. (That is what exit on close means.)

Next, replace

```
f.dispose();
```

with

```
f.setVisible(false);
```

That will close the window, and it will get disposed.

The next step is making your window work. The real reason I don't think you were getting any key events is because of the next problem, but you can add.

```
w.setFocusable(true);
w.requestFocus();
```

That way your window will have focus.

Finally, the real issue I think is your run method. It sounds like your game loop is running on the EDT. You can try this to start a new thread.

```
public void run() {
    init();

    new Thread( ()-> gameLoop()).start();
}
```

That should get your application running, it is a bit of a hack and you should create a SwingWorker, this is a gist of the idea.